# how to color the table data in primeng

Tags: angularjs, datatable, formatting, conditional-statements, primeng

Unable apply background color/color the text present in the table data.
Below mentioned is the code.

```
<p-column field="unitCount" header="Unit Count" [editable]="true" 
[sortable]="true" ></p-column>
<p-column field="serviceCostPerUnit" header="Service Cost Per Unit" 
[editable]="true" [sortable]="true" >
  <ng-template let-col let-unitgridtask="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <span>{{unitgridtask[col.field] | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</p-column>
```

Comment: Here is the solution for background-color for table data.
 
    <p-column styleClass="editableData" field="unitCount" header="Unit Count" [editable]="true" [sortable]="true" ></p-column>      All i need is to color the rows of entire table when editable = true as green & when editable = false as red

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it by the following way:
in your `style.css` add:

```
td {
  color: red;
}
```

Hope it helps!